# mapMaybes / catMaybe working different in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: list, parsing, haskell, ubuntu

I have a Haskell program that reads the content of an input file and parses it to sort and remove duplicates. This program has been dormant for some time now, and I have a need to resurrect it. I tell you this just for some historical context on the problem.

When I re-enabled the program, I found that it was not working. My debugging has isolated the problem to the code that parses and "cleans" the input file. What happens after this is insignificant to this problem, since I end up with an empty list of candidate records from the input file.

I write and test this program on my Windows laptop, then deploy and build the source on the Ubuntu server where is needs to run. As part of my debugging, I have broken the text parsing into several descreet steps, and the part where is runs catMaybe on the output of the last step is where I get the empty list, but only when I run it on the Ubuntu server.

Here is the source in main that demonstrates the problem:

```
    main = do
        [ inFileName ] <- getArgs
        sFile <- readFile inFileName
        let lrec = lines sFile
        putStrLn $ "Number of lines read from the file: " ++ show (length lrec)
        let prec = map processLine lrec
        putStrLn $ "Number of processed lines is " ++ show (length prec)
        -- let persons = mapMaybe processLine lrec
        let persons = catMaybes prec
        putStrLn $ "Number of filtered person records: " ++ show (length persons)
        let records = sortBy (compare `on` personEmployeeID) persons
        putStrLn $ "Number of records read and sorted is " ++ show (length records)

        {-
            Compare and warn about employees with duplicate records.
        -}
        let srec = groupBy ((==) `on` personEmployeeID) records
        putStrLn $ "Number of unique record groups is " ++ show (length srec)
        let dups = map (personEmployeeID . head) $ filter ((> 1) . length) srec
        putStrLn $ "Number of dups: " ++ show (length dups)
        unless (null dups) $ putStrLn $ "WARNING: Duplicate employees: " ++ show dups

        -- Remove the duplicates
        let cleanedRecords = map head srec
        putStrLn $ "Number of records in cleanedRecords is " ++ show (length cleanedRecords)
```

As you may noticed from the commented line, I tried this using mapMaybe in place of catMaybes with no change whatsoever in the results. And here is the code from the processLine method where the comment shows the format of the input records:

```
    {-
        Splits a line of the input file into fields.  The format includes 11 columns,
        separated by semicolons.  The 10th columns is required to be 'A' or 'S',
        indicating the user is active or short-term; otherwise we ignore that line.

        Sample Line:
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        99XXXXX17;MXXX                          ;TXXXXX         ;MIXXXXXX                      ;RAA  CBP;RAA;19910929;19910929;19910929;A;             ;
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        emp id   ;first name                    ;middle name    ;last name                     ;loc code;dpt;hiredate;servdate;statdate;s;note         ;
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        * s = status
    -}
    processLine :: String -> Maybe Person
    processLine line = 
        let (_ :: String, _ :: String, _ :: String, result) = 
                line =~ "^(.+);(.+);(.+);(.+);(.+);(.+);(.+);(.+);(.+);(A|S);(.+);$" 
        in case result of
            [empid, fname, mname, lname, lcode, dept, hdate, srvdate, stdate, status, note]
                -> Just $ Person empid (trim fname) (trim mname) (trim lname)
                                 (trim lcode) dept hdate srvdate stdate  (readStatus status) (trim note)
            _   -> Nothing
```

When I run this code on my windows laptop, it produces the following output:

```
    Number of lines read from the file: 47793
    Number of processed lines is 47793
    Number of filtered person records: 32993
    Number of records read and sorted is 32993
    Number of unique record groups is 32949
    Number of dups: 44
    WARNING: Duplicate employees: [ {List removed for privacy } ]
    Number of records in cleanedRecords is 32949
    C:>cabal --version
    cabal-install version 1.22.4.0
    using version 1.22.3.0 of the Cabal library
    C:>ghc --version
    The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3
```

When I run the same code against the same input file on either of two different Ubuntu servers, each with a different version of Ubuntu and Haskell, I get the following output:

```
    Number of lines read from the file: 47793
    Number of processed lines is 47793
    Number of filtered person records: 0
    Number of records read and sorted is 0
    Number of unique record groups is 0
    Number of dups: 0
    Number of records in cleanedRecords is 0
    xx:~/$ cabal --version
    cabal-install version 0.14.0
    using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library
    xx:~/$ ghc --version
    The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
```

...and from another Ubuntu server:

```
    Number of lines read from the file: 47793
    Number of processed lines is 47793
    Number of filtered person records: 0
    Number of records read and sorted is 0
    Number of unique record groups is 0
    Number of dups: 0
    Number of records in cleanedRecords is 0
    yy:~/$ cabal --version
    cabal-install version 0.10.2
    using version 1.10.2.0 of the Cabal library
    yy:~/$ ghc --version
    The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.1
```

As usual, I am baffled. I am ready to try anything.

Any ideas?

Dave

Comment: It looks like the differences start before it reaches `mapMaybe`/`catMaybes`. The number of lines read from the file is different.

Comment: I've tried your code on my Ubuntu machine. With a sample line in a text file the filter works fine. Are you sure the files on your ubuntu machine follow the same format?  For example, do they have a non empty note field?

Comment: Yeah, now I really feel stupid. In my haste to get this written up, I did use the wrong input file on my Windows machine. I have corrected that error and edited the OP to reflect that corrected result. I have been told that what I am reporting is not possible, and I agree. I am told that there must be some difference in the input files that explains the difference in output. In the last example, I copied the code and input file from my Windows laptop to that Ubuntu server; therefore, I am confident they are the same. wc -l on the input file confirms the line count. Thank for the comments.

Answer (score 8):

And the answer is...

Windows vs Unix line endings.

I added code to print out the first few lines of input and saw the \r on the end of each line. I ran the file through dos2unix. Now I get the same results on the Ubuntu system.

Thank you for pointing me to the input file as the source of the problem.